# Is there any way to remove letters from a word starting with a Vowel? Python

Tags: python, program-slicing

For every word in the sentence , If the word starts with a vowel, encode it as the first and last letter of the word. I don't know how to do it. Any help?

Example:- Iterator to iterate on each character of the input string
Output should be : Ir to ie on eh character of the it string.

maybe use slicing?

Comment: "*I don't know how to do it*" -> this is obviously homework, what have you tried?

Comment: If you're starting with each sentence as a separate string, then it might be useful to first use the string.split() method to produce a list of words from that sentence. You could then do some conditional operation on each of these words (possibly using slicing as you mention, then join them back together somehow into the transformed sentence

Comment: When facing such problem, split it in smaller problems and implement each at a time. To solve your problem first try to implement the following: 1) A function that given a string splits it into a list of words. 2) A function that given a list of words iterates them and obtains a word at each iteration 3) A function that given a word extracts the first character 4) A function that given a character returns True if it's a vowel.  Now you only need to combine your 4 implementations and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the sentence into words, and then for each word check what character it starts with. The, you can use a ternary expression to either return the first and last characters or the entire word:

```py
original = 'Iterator to iterate on each character of the input string'

vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
result = ' '.join(w[0] + w[-1] if w[0] in vowels else w for w in orig.split(' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vowel="aiueo" #Making sure to list all of the vowels
sentence="Iterator to iterate on each" #Defining sentence
result=[i if i[0].lower() not in vowel else i[0]+i[-1] for i in sentence.split()] #checking for every words in the sentence and replacing each word with i[0] + i[1]if it contains vowel 
print(" ".join(result)) #Printing the result
```

Hope it could help :>